# Exoplayer a little gap in playlist when using ConcatenatingMediaSource

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using ConcatenatingMediaSource to make hls urls playlist for my ExoPlayer.

when playing media sources by local files, it works fine without gap.

However, when playing media sources by hls urls, It noticeably shows gap while transition (first video to second one)

I want my media source transit smoothly in ConcatenatingMediaSource.

How can I achieve this?

Guide me please.

This below is my init code.

```
    val playerView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.playerView)
    val concatenatedSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()

    val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(mContext!!)
    trackSelector.parameters = trackSelector.buildUponParameters().build()

    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
    val hlsMediaSource: HlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .setAllowChunklessPreparation(true)
        .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("https://multiplatform-f.akamaihd.net/i/multi/april11/sintel/sintel-hd_,512x288_450_b,640x360_700_b,768x432_1000_b,1024x576_1400_m,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8"))

    concatenatedSource.addMediaSource(hlsMediaSource)

    val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(mContext)
        .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
        .build()

    player.setMediaSource(concatenatedSource)
    player.addAnalyticsListener(EventLogger(trackSelector))
    player.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
        override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
            super.onPlayerError(error)
        }
    })

    playerView?.player = player
    playerView?.player?.prepare()
    playerView?.player?.playWhenReady = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have this kind of issues, you should try CacheDataSource while building MediaItem objects. This resolved my issues. Thanks